# Build status picture stays at "build unknown"

Tags: travis-ci

Even if the builds are passing on Travis, the Build Status picture seems to have stopped changing. It still says "build unknown".

[image: build unknown]

My `.travis.yml` contains:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.12"
  - "0.11"
  - "0.10"
  - "iojs-v2.1.0"
  - "iojs-v1.0.4"
services:
  - mongodb
```

What's the problem?

Comment: paste your ```.travis.yml``` file, and maybe a link to your repository?

Comment: I've edited my question. My repo is https://github.com/FriendsBet/API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to a [Travis issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3996#issuecomment-109450188) that is now corrected.